# Почему не работает кнопка в другом классе?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton

Возникла проблема, кнопки созданные в другом классе не работают, хотя и принадлежат виджету который принадлежит основному окну.

Мне это нужно, чтобы избежать соединения отдельных модулей с главным, так как в ином случае у класса будет много методов.
Наследованием класса от `QWidget` не подойдёт, так как один модуль может содержать несколько виджетов в подчинении.

Что нужно сделать чтобы нажатие кнопок происходило также как и в классе от наследованным от `QWidget`?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, qApp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QLineEdit, QRadioButton, QGridLayout, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QFileDialog


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.FLAG = True
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.wid1 = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.wid1)
        self.qh = QHBoxLayout(self.wid1)

        self.vq = QVBoxLayout(self.wid1)
        self.qh.addItem(self.vq)

        self.main_wid = QWidget(self)
        self.nav_wid = QWidget(self)

        self.vq.addWidget(self.nav_wid)  # Предположим, что нельзя в класс передать Layout
        self.vq.addWidget(self.main_wid)

        self.but = QPushButton()
        self.but.setText("Setting")
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.rename)
        self.but.show()
        self.qh.addWidget(self.but)

        self.tmp = list()

    def rename(self):
        for i in self.tmp:  # Закрытие всех объектов на виджете
            i.hide()
        self.tmp.clear()

        self.FLAG = not self.FLAG  # Смена модулей
        if self.FLAG:
            mod = Module1(self.main_wid, self.nav_wid)
            self.tmp = mod.main_content()
            self.tmp = mod.navigation()
        else:
            mod = Module2(self.main_wid, self.nav_wid)
            self.tmp = mod.main_content()
            self.tmp = mod.navigation()


class Module1:
    def __init__(self, wid, nav):
        self.list_obj = list()
        self.wid = wid
        self.nav = nav

    def main_content(self):
        count = 0
        for i in ["До", "Ре"]:
            self.push = QPushButton(self.wid)
            self.push.setText(i)
            self.push.show()
            self.push.move(50, 50 * count)
            self.push.clicked.connect(self.click_but)  # Не реагирует на команды
            self.list_obj.append(self.push)
            count += 1

        return self.list_obj

    def navigation(self):
        self.lab = QLabel(self.nav)
        self.lab.setText("Ноты")
        self.lab.show()
        self.list_obj.append(self.lab)
        return self.list_obj

    def click_but(self):
        print("Module 1 OK")


class Module2:
    def __init__(self, wid, nav):
        self.list_obj = list()
        self.wid = wid
        self.nav = nav

    def main_content(self):
        count = 0
        for i in ["1", "2"]:
            self.push = QPushButton(self.wid)
            self.push.setText(i)
            self.push.show()
            self.push.move(50, 50 * count)
            self.push.clicked.connect(self.click_but)
            self.list_obj.append(self.push)
            count += 1

        return self.list_obj

    def navigation(self):
        self.lab = QLabel(self.nav)
        self.lab.setText("Цифры")
        self.lab.show()
        self.list_obj.append(self.lab)
        return self.list_obj

    def click_but(self):
        print("Module 1 OK")


def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback1):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не проверял логику вашего приложения, так как она для меня не очень понятна. 
Я только исправил ошибки, которые получил при запуске вашего приложения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QLineEdit, QRadioButton, QGridLayout, QLabel, \
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QFileDialog, QAction, qApp


class Module1:
    def __init__(self, wid, nav):
    
        self.list_obj = list()
        self.wid = wid
        self.nav = nav

    def main_content(self):
        count = 0
        for i in ["До", "Ре"]:
            self.push = QPushButton(self.wid)
            self.push.setText(i)
            self.push.show()
            self.push.move(50, 50 * count)
            self.push.clicked.connect(self.click_but)  # Не реагирует на команды
            self.list_obj.append(self.push)
            count += 1

        return self.list_obj

    def navigation(self):
        self.lab = QLabel(self.nav)
        self.lab.setText("Ноты")
        self.lab.show()
        self.list_obj.append(self.lab)
        return self.list_obj

    def click_but(self):
        print("Module 1 OK")


class Module2:
    def __init__(self, wid, nav):
        self.list_obj = list()
        self.wid = wid
        self.nav = nav

    def main_content(self):
        count = 0
        for i in ["1", "2"]:
            self.push = QPushButton(self.wid)
            self.push.setText(i)
            self.push.show()
            self.push.move(50, 50 * count)
            self.push.clicked.connect(self.click_but)
            self.list_obj.append(self.push)
            count += 1

        return self.list_obj

    def navigation(self):
        self.lab = QLabel(self.nav)
        self.lab.setText("Цифры")
        self.lab.show()
        self.list_obj.append(self.lab)
        return self.list_obj

    def click_but(self):
        print("Module 1 OK")


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.FLAG = True

        self.wid1 = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.wid1)
        self.qh = QHBoxLayout(self.wid1)
        
        self.left_widget = QWidget()                         # +++
        self.vq = QVBoxLayout(self.left_widget)              # - (self.wid1)
# -        self.qh.addItem(self.vq)

        self.main_wid = QWidget(self)
        self.main_wid.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ccffbd;')
        self.nav_wid = QWidget(self)
        self.nav_wid.setStyleSheet('background-color: #bdccff;')

        self.vq.addWidget(self.nav_wid)  
        self.vq.addWidget(self.main_wid)

        self.but = QPushButton()
        self.but.setText("Setting")
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.rename)
#        self.but.show()
        
        
        self.qh.addWidget(self.left_widget)                      # +++
        self.qh.addWidget(self.but)

        self.tmp = list()

    def rename(self):
        for i in self.tmp:  # Закрытие всех объектов на виджете
            i.hide()
        self.tmp.clear()

        self.FLAG = not self.FLAG  # Смена модулей
        if self.FLAG:
            mod = Module1(self.main_wid, self.nav_wid)
            self.tmp = mod.main_content()
            self.tmp = mod.navigation()
        else:
            mod = Module2(self.main_wid, self.nav_wid)
            self.tmp = mod.main_content()
            self.tmp = mod.navigation()        


def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback1):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(500, 500)
    ex.show()
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

Теперь ваши кнопки реагируют на нажатие, проверьте. 
Но логику вашего приложения надо пересмотреть.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QLineEdit, QRadioButton, QGridLayout, QLabel, \
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QFileDialog, QAction, qApp


class Module1:
    def __init__(self, wid, nav):
    
        self.list_obj = list()
        self.wid = wid
        self.nav = nav

    def main_content(self):
        count = 0
        for i in ["До", "Ре"]:
            self.push = QPushButton(self.wid)
            self.push.setText(i)
            self.push.show()
            self.push.move(50, 50 * count)

#           self.push.clicked.connect(self.click_but)  # Не реагирует на команды 
           
            self.push.clicked.connect(lambda ch, text=i: self.click_but(text))  # +++
#                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
        
            self.list_obj.append(self.push)
            count += 1
        return self.list_obj

    def navigation(self):
        self.lab = QLabel(self.nav)
        self.lab.setText("Ноты")
        self.lab.show()
        self.list_obj.append(self.lab)
        return self.list_obj

    def click_but(self, text):                                     # +++ text
        print(f"Module 1 OK:  {text}")                             # +++ text


class Module2:
    def __init__(self, wid, nav):
        self.list_obj = list()
        self.wid = wid
        self.nav = nav

    def main_content(self):
        count = 0
        for i in ["1", "2"]:
            self.push = QPushButton(self.wid)
            self.push.setText(i)
            self.push.show()
            self.push.move(50, 50 * count)
# +++                                 vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            self.push.clicked.connect(lambda ch, text=i: self.click_but(text))
            
            self.list_obj.append(self.push)
            count += 1

        return self.list_obj

    def navigation(self):
        self.lab = QLabel(self.nav)
        self.lab.setText("Цифры")
        self.lab.show()
        self.list_obj.append(self.lab)
        return self.list_obj

    def click_but(self, text):                                    # +++
#        print("Module 1 OK")
        print(f"Module 2 OK:  {text}")                            # +++


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.FLAG = True

        self.wid1 = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.wid1)
        self.qh = QHBoxLayout(self.wid1)
        
        self.left_widget = QWidget()                         # +++
        self.vq = QVBoxLayout(self.left_widget)              # - (self.wid1)
# -        self.qh.addItem(self.vq)

        self.main_wid = QWidget(self)
        self.main_wid.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ccffbd;')
        self.nav_wid = QWidget(self)
        self.nav_wid.setStyleSheet('background-color: #bdccff;')

        self.vq.addWidget(self.nav_wid)  
        self.vq.addWidget(self.main_wid)

        self.but = QPushButton()
        self.but.setText("Setting")
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.rename)
#        self.but.show()
        
        
        self.qh.addWidget(self.left_widget)                      # +++
        self.qh.addWidget(self.but)

        self.tmp = list()

    def rename(self):
        for i in self.tmp:  # Закрытие всех объектов на виджете
            i.hide()
        self.tmp.clear()

        self.FLAG = not self.FLAG  # Смена модулей
        if self.FLAG:
            self.mod = Module1(self.main_wid, self.nav_wid)
            self.tmp = self.mod.main_content()
            self.tmp = self.mod.navigation()
        else:
            mod = Module2(self.main_wid, self.nav_wid)
            self.tmp = mod.main_content()
            self.tmp = mod.navigation()        


def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback1):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(500, 500)
    ex.show()
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @greymaster я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте и напишите, пожалуйста, все ли так.

Comment: Действительно работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Мне показалось, что пока вам дополнительные классы не нужны. Хотя, что вы собираетесь делать дальше, я не знаю.

Просто попробуйте мой пример.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.wid = QWidget()
        self.wid.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ccffbd;')
        
        self.tmp = QPushButton()
        self.tmp.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ccbdff;')
        self.tmp.clicked.connect(self.click_but)
        self.qv = QVBoxLayout(self.wid)
        self.qv.addWidget(self.tmp)
        
        self.but = QPushButton()
        self.but.setText("Setting")
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.rename)

        self.qh = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.qh.addWidget(self.wid)        
        self.qh.addWidget(self.but)

    def rename(self):
        if self.tmp.text() == '???' or self.tmp.text() == 'Не нажимай на меня':
           self.tmp.setText("Нажми на меня") 
        else:
           self.tmp.setText("Не нажимай на меня") 

    def click_but(self):
        if self.tmp.text():    
            print(self.tmp.text())           


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(300, 150)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]